# Toggle Class with Data-attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Data attributes to get an element in jQuery as below

```
<a class="toggleArrow">Toggle Me</a>
<span class="arrow collapse" data-target="trgt1">
    <i class=fa fa-arrow-right""></i>
</span>

<span class="arrow collapse" data-target="trgt2">
    <i class=fa fa-arrow-left""></i>
</span>
```

JQuery is

```
$("a.toggleArrow").off().on("click", function () {
    $("span.arrow").each(function () {
        var dataTarget = $(this).data("target");
        if (dataTarget == "tgrt1") {
            dataTarget.toggleClass("collapse expand");
        }
    });
});
```

Can we use this way but it does not seem to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to refer to the current element in the `each`. `dataTarget` is a string, you cannot call jQuery method on it `dataTarget.toggleClass("collapse expand");`

```
if ($(this).data('target') == 'tgrt1') {
    $(this).toggleClass("collapse expand");
    //^^^^^
}
```

---

No need of looping, use [attribute-value selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select all the `<span>` elements having class of *arrow* and `data-target` value as `tgrt1`.

```
$("a.toggleArrow").off().on("click", function() {
    $("span.arrow[data-target='tgrt1']").toggleClass("collapse expand");
});
```

Comment: @Gags No, you're not, use `$(this)` to refer to the current element. Check update

Comment: yup.. this is fine. You are editing like anything :)

Answer (score 1):

`dataTarget` variable contains string. You cannot use jQuery function onto a string.

```
dataTarget.toggleClass("collapse expand");
```

You need to replace with

```
$(this).toggleClass("collapse expand");
```