# How to make slideToggle dynamic in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page where multiple div and within each div there is a option to click and toggle the information, I am able to create by defining different IDs of `DIV` but I think that can be done somehow dynamically, here is what I have created in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/onnkzwqy/)

CSS

```
.boxwrap {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}
.boxwrap_inner {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.noDisplay {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="boxwrap">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="button1">Go</a>
    <div class="boxwrap_inner noDisplay" id="content1">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="boxwrap">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="button2">Go</a>
    <div class="boxwrap_inner noDisplay" id="content2">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
    $("#content1").slideToggle(200);
});
$('#button2').click(function () {
    $("#content2").slideToggle(200);
});
```

Comment: Look at [Toggle Class with Data-attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361007/toggle-class-with-data-attribute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this:

```js
$('.boxwrap > a').click(function () {
  $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
});
```

```css
.boxwrap {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}
.boxwrap_inner {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.noDisplay {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxwrap">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="button1">Go</a>
    <div class="boxwrap_inner noDisplay" id="content1">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="boxwrap">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="button2">Go</a>
    <div class="boxwrap_inner noDisplay" id="content2">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That isn't a good idea to use only `a` in selector. `$('.boxwrap > a')` is better.

Comment: Good luck @SanjeevK :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

It's better to specify the element with it's parent on which you're calling a click event.

```
$('.boxwrap > a').click(function(){
  $(this).next('div').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers rely on the fact that the DOM is going to remain the same and the next() element after the button will always be the content div.

For a more robust solution, I would add a class to the buttons in the boxwrap(i.e. .boxbtn) and a class to the content divs (i.e. boxcontent) and then I would do something like the following:

```
$('.boxbtn').click(function () {
   $(this).closest('.boxwrap')..find('.boxcontent').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here with 2 options**

1. using relative attribute value
2. using finding relative don element

```js
/*$('.toggle_link').click(function () {
 $($(this).data('toggle')).slideToggle(200);
});

OR
*/
$('.toggle_link').click(function () {
 $(this).parent().find('.noDisplay').slideToggle(200);
});
```

```css
.boxwrap{float:left; width:200px; height:250px; border:1px solid #ccc; margin:0 5px 0 0; text-align:center; box-sizing:border-box; padding:10px;}
.boxwrap_inner{float:left; width:100%; background:#ddd; padding:5px 0; text-align:center;}
.noDisplay{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxwrap">
 <a href="javascript:;" id="button1" data-toggle="#content1" class="toggle_link">Go</a>
    <div class="boxwrap_inner noDisplay" id="content1">
     Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="boxwrap">
 <a href="javascript:;" id="button2" data-toggle="#content2" class="toggle_link">Go</a>
    <div class="boxwrap_inner noDisplay" id="content2">
     Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```