# Add body class when mobile menu is clicked ( aria-expanded="true" )

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've searched similar questions for some time now but haven't been able to find what i need.

```
<button class="menu-toggle icons-menu activated" aria-expanded="true" aria-pressed="true" id="mobile-menu">Menu</button>
```

I've tried dozens of variations of this code to add a class to the body element when the mobile menu button is clicked and the aria-expanded attribute is changed from false to true.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    if ($(".menu-toggle").attr("aria-expanded") === "true") {
    
        $('body').addClass('mobile-menu-open');
    
    } else {
    
        $('body').removeClass('mobile-menu-open');
    
    }
    
});
```

Comment: You need to bind a click event to the button and then check the attribute of the clicked element in the event.  This is pretty similar to what you are trying to do but with data attributes instead of normal attributes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361007/toggle-class-with-data-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your aria-expanded is being changed when clicked .. your issue is because you're not binding to when the user clicks the button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(body).on('.menu-toggle','click',function(){
        if ($(this).attr("aria-expanded") === "true") {
            $('body').addClass('mobile-menu-open');
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('mobile-menu-open');
        }
    })
})
```

Please try the above instead and see if that works.

Comment: I would use `$(this)` instead of `$(".menu-toggle")` inside your click event, and you probably want to toggle your aria attribute too otherwise it will just work once

Comment: As would I actually! I'll update this.

Comment: Thanks but i tried this and it doesn't add the class to the body element.